# A word or phrase to say:- its redundant to compare the two subjects

Tags: grammar, phrases, synonyms, sentence, filler-words

1. I am trying to make a person understand a theory. I do so by at
   first, describing in lengthy depth the game of "peek-a-boo" and how
   babies have no concept of the real world.
2. I then would like to bring the person back to how the person and I
   are OBVIOUSLY far more intellectual than a baby so why would i even
   compare us to a baby?

[imagine a long in-depth science text about babies and the game of peek-a-boo]

> *In conclusion. They genuinely believe the mother has left the physical plane of being. Thats why peek-a-boo game is so effective with babies.*

A word or phrase to say:- its redundant to compare the two subjects

> ***Now obviously its redundant for an adult to be compared to a newborn baby***

OR

> ***A needless endeavor to you and I,** however, this fact is the fundamental understanding to this theory*

OR

> ***It might seem barren to** to look at a newborn baby, in order to understand an abstract theory*

### TL;DR:-

a better way to say:-
"IT MIGHT SEEM POINTLESS TO COMPARE xyz TO 123" ##

Comment: First, it's not true babies "have no concept of the real world." What you describe with your peek-a-boo game is a child learning *object permanence*, a stage in early childhood development. They have a concept of the real world, just not a totally developed concept. Second, you're misusing "redundant." When something is described as "redundant," it means something else already serves that purpose and having another thing serve that purpose is wasteful, superfluous, an unnecessary excess. It's NOT redundant to compare two subjects unless it's already been done and doesn't need to be repeated.

Comment: It's not redundant. It's the opposite of redundant.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - I evidently wasn't trying to literally explain the theory of object permanence. It is also apparent that I wasn't putting in energy into overly using vocabulary into my question where it was not necessary as I felt the community here is admirably highly intellectual enough to get the gist of what i am trying to convey and actually fill in the gaps that are necessary. Aka, as much as I appreciate the correction on the example theory. it wasn't the point.

Comment: I know redudant is incorrect and thats why I am here. If it was truly "redundant" then why even compare to begin with? Thats why...admittedly ridiculous, but nonetheless the example was trying to help anyone steer me in the right direction of:-

"it may seem pointless to compare XYZ to 123, however..." or "it may seem irrelevant to compare XYZ to 123, but"

Comment: You're looking for the right words to say the wrong thing, which to me is that you wasted the reader's time. Trust me, if I mansplain something for the sake of comparison, it's extra mansplaining to apologize for it. Edit out the extraneous and you won't have to explain. If you're attached to an endless peekaboo story, ask the reader What is the parallel?

Comment: *It may seem pointless to compare XYZ to 123, however...* However *what*? Are you saying that it may seem pointless to compare them but in fact it's not pointless to compare them?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: "Why am I telling you this?" "You might think I'm wasting your time" "'Where is all this leading?' you ask..."

Answer (score 0):

You could try the word, incommensurate. For example:

> The two things are incommensurate

Meaning that the two things are not comparable. However, I'd say the word is rather formal and a little grand.

Comment: yes! this is definitely in the right path. 

>You can compare apples to oranges but its incommensurate to do

Answer (score 0):

The a few simple and casual examples to put something like this, if I'm fully understanding what you're trying to express, would be:

> Although longwinded, I went through such a granular comparison and explanation **in the interest of thoroughness**.

The above conveys your reasons for seemingly giving an overly grandoise walk through to most likely keep the reader or listener from jumping to an early conclusion of it all being on the border of condescending or the "just likes to sound smart / hear himself or herself talk" pitfall.

Another way, along the same lines, would be to put it as:

> While I recognize that most likely there wasn't a need for most of the details that we all already know, **leaving as little room as possible for ambiguity or vagueness** will guarantee a level field of understanding among us all.

This would fit in much more with something at the high academic level during a talk about some dry topic, or topics.